# POST request, Cannot set headers after client, updating database and redirecting

Tags: node.js, http, post, header

Im trying to update my update my mongodb database and then redirect the user back to the page with the form.

It's the usual problem of
'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'
that's often posted on here but couldn't find any solution for my problem.

I'm using nodeJS and express, no php or jquery.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('user');

var createUser = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    var user = new User({
        "firstname": req.body.firstname,
        "surname": req.body.surname,
        "email": req.body.email,
        "age": req.body.age
    });
    user.save(function(err, newUser){
        if(!err){
            res.send(newUser);
        }
        else{
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    });
    res.redirect('/');
};

module.exports.createUser = createUser;
```

I get the error 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'

It does update my mongodb database but crashes server after.

Not very skilled with headers in requests, any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query was successfully executed, the `if` block in here is executed, which is sending some response to the client. Then the rest of the execution continues till the `res.redirect('/')` which is again tryin to send some response (from whatever is in the `/` route).

```
user.save(function(err, newUser){
  if(!err){
    // Here >>
    res.send(newUser);
  }
  else{
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }
});
// and finally >>
res.redirect('/');
```

So either do `return res.send(newUser);` or only do the redirect at the end *not both*